# I am checking for errors in YOUTUBE API V3

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to receive the number of playlist and playlist for the YouTube channel, but I have not received the normal value.

Youtube Channel id = UCfgCVM6Thui54cwUqdH1XNA

That's have 16 play list.

But Youtube-v3-api return to 8 play list.

I want to know if there is an API error or a Query problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Youtube's [Playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list). I tried to using your Channel ID and here's the number of playlists it returned:

```
(these were the parameters in the Try-it)
    part -> snippet
    channelId -> UCfgCVM6Thui54cwUqdH1XNA
    maxResults -> 50
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistListResponse",
 "etag": "\"GM4ZnRh2gk1X1BLWgHklTm-3cgQ/brsESCW4H5vAYLrCxJV_YEwdEIE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 16, //confirmed, you have 16 playlists
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
  "items": [
  .
  .
```

I also checked how many `channelTitles` (representing a playlist) there were under `"items"` and **got 16 counts**. 
 Hope that helps.